# Bootstrap. Removing the border around the thumbnail images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I used bootstrap thumbnail class to create a grid of clickable images. For some reason, they have a border and its annoying me.

HTML:

```
<div class = "the-grid">
<div class = "container">        
<div class = "row">
              <div class = "col-md-4">
                <div class = "thumbnail">
                    <image src = "Images/data.png"/>
                </div>
                 <div class = "thumbnail">
                    <image src = "Images/cloud.png"/>
                </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
.the-grid{
background-color: #efefef;    
border-bottom: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
min-height: 100%;
}
.the-grid .row .thumbnail{
border: 0px;
box-shadow: none;
border-radius:0px;
background-color: #000;
}

.the-grid .row .thumbnail  img:hover {
 background-color: #000 !importantl        
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can override the default bootstrap thumbnail border setting by adding this to your CSS file:

```
.thumbnail {
border: 0;
}
```

You can also simulate this by inspecting the properties of a thumbnail in Chrome.  Find  .thumbnail properties and uncheck border.  You will see it disappear from your image.
[Screenshot of .thumbnail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av3gS.png)
Once you add the code to your CSS file.  Re-inspect and you will see that the border property with a strikethrough.
[.thumbnail with no border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R18Eu.png)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove all border property's from .thumbnail and all borders will be removed

```
.the-grid .row .thumbnail{
box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: No luck. Its still there.

Comment: http://codepen.io/riogrande/pen/KdyeoG 
check this link, from css that you give here i removed border, but if border is still here then this is not only selector that is targeting thumbnail. Check it with firebug or devtools to see exactly.

Answer (score 1):

why dont you just add the border class like this...

```
<img class="img-thumbnail border border-0" src="photo_location..." alt="photo">
```

Answer (score 0):

Go into your bootstrap.min.css (if you have it local, otherwise you have to download it) and search for: ".thumbnail" and then delete the part where it says "border" or so.. Don't have any bootstrap version aviable otherwise I will say you where that is, sry.

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting the element, the padding was what i needed to adjust on mine as well as the border to remove that box just in case anyone else runs into this.

`thumbnail {
padding: 0;
border: 0;
}`

Answer (score 0):

If you using latest Bootstrap,

use class  "img-thumbnail" on your img tag !

Example:

```
<img class ="img-thumbnail" src="Your_Path_Image" alt="">
```

& Add class "img-thumbnail" on your file custom CSS Bootstrap!

Example:

```css
.img-thumbnail{
    background: none;
    border: none;
}
```